# Can not resolve kotlin.test.Test in commonMain

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to create a KMM library for tests. Lets call it MyTestLib. MyTestLib will be consumed in application projects that also consume the main business logic. MyTestLib will be test interfaces.

here is the build.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.7.21"
}

group = "com.xingpeds"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        withJava()
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
    js(BOTH) {
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting
        val jvmTest by getting
        val jsMain by getting
        val jsTest by getting
        val nativeMain by getting
        val nativeTest by getting
    }
}
```

[image]

```
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.fail

interface TestTemplate {
    @Test
    fun firstTemplate() {
        fail("red stage")
    }
}
```

[image]

```
class ConcreteTest : TestTemplate
```

./gradlew test

[image]

Why is kotlin.test.Test not found in the commonMain?

Comment: The compilation fails in JVM target because it's impossible to determine automatically which JVM test framework to use for it.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you have to add the `test-junit5` dependency to the `jvmTest` `sourceSet`:

```
    sourceSets {
        ...

        getByName("jvmTest") {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure why this magically enables `commonTest` to see the `test-common` and `test-annotations-common` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped removing kotlin test dependency from `commonMain` and moving it only to `commonTest`:

```
    val commonTest by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
```

Where `libs.kotlin.test` is `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:<kotlin version>`